# api-maps.yandex.ru 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: яндекс-карты

Имеется сайт http://ram5.ru/ на нем имеется карта, долгое время все прекрасно работало.

С недавнего времени на карте пропали метки и в консоли ошибка:

GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/geoxml/1.2/geoxml.xml?callback=jsonp1572518963787&key=ABv5JVEBAAAAyyEnDQIA39pXlNB42fDldUYxqNzDd6-REVIAAAAAAAAAAADbHm8p1nYg2ZHJSXvDdSjscmp34w%3D%3D&origin=jsapi1YMapsML&url=http%3A%2F%2Fram5.ru%2Fincludes%2Fcreate_ymapsml.php net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Вас заблокировали. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_кодов_состояния_HTTP

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков причина явно не в этом, потому что карта отображается)

Comment: перейдите на актуальную версию апи и зарегайте ключ

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с документацией о подключения API Яндекс.Карт:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/#load__param

Судя по строке запроса, вы не передаете обязательный параметр apikey.